# Spring cron @scheduled method running twice

Tags: java, spring, scheduling

The method with @Scheduled annotation is executed twice (cron entry 0 */5 * * * *).
I have read that the problem is probably with context which is loaded twice.

My web.xml file looks like that.

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>
      WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml
   </param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
   <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
   <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

After I removed the listener from web.xml the scheduling was executed correcty once.
However there was another problem. When I visited the website there was error message.

Cannot be the problem with Dispatcher entry  where mvc-config is occurred twice in web.xml?

Comment: ContextLoaderListener will load all beans that are configured on root application config in your case is mvc-config.xml and DispatcherServlet will load all beans that are configured on servlet application context in you case is the same mvc-config.xml and hence beans are loaded twice, for best practice separate root app config from servlet app config

Comment: You mean to separate view resolver, multipart resolver, scan of controllers and other web stuffs into servlet.xml and other stuffs (persistence, ...) into e.g. app.config?

Comment: Yes, let the first one mvc-config.xml like what you put on web.xml and the second be root-config.xml

Comment: It seems that it works correctly now. Many thanks :)